# What is the time complexity for tf.transpose in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-complexity

For example, assume we have an tensor `a` with input shape
(10,32,32,3)
Which means 10 32*32 RGB pictures with NHWC format

and I want to use `tf.transpose(b, perm=[0, 3, 1, 2])` to convert it into NCHW format

What is the time complexity of this operation?

---------FORWARD---------

I found that the time complexity of numpy transpose function is O(1), according to the following link

https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58279082.shtml

Is that the same in tf?

Answer (score 0):

Matrix transposition for a 2D matrix is `O(dim1*dim2)`.

For a 3D matrix it would be `O(dim1*dim2*dim3)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L2029-L2107):

```
@compatibility(numpy)
  In `numpy` transposes are memory-efficient constant time operations as they
  simply return a new view of the same data with adjusted `strides`.
  TensorFlow does not support strides, so `transpose` returns a new tensor with
  the items permuted.
@end_compatibility
```

That means that the complexity depends on the dimensions of your tensor. Assuming that you have `k` dimensions of `n`-size each, it would mean `O(n^k)`.